# Pandas. Подключение к БД postgres и запрос к таблицам

Tags: postgresql, pandas

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно подключиться к БД Postgres, если структура БД такая:
общая витрина баз данных, в которой есть несколько БД с таблицами.

Код следующий:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
try:
    # пытаемся подключиться к базе данных
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, user=user, password=password,
                            host=host, port=port)

except:
    # в случае сбоя подключения будет выведено сообщение в STDOUT
    print('Can`t establish connection to database')

query = """SELECT * FROM "DB1"."table1";"""
pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

Пробовал без Pandas выполнить подключение:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()  
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM "DB1"."table1"') 
all_users = cursor.fetchall() cursor.close() conn.close()
```

Подключение к общей витрине БД выполняется успешно, а вот попытка выполнить запрос выдает ошибку:

```
pandas.errors.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM "DB1"."table1";': error with status PGRES_EMPTY_QUERY and no message from the libpq
```

Возможно, неверный синтаксис в query при обращении к БД и таблице.
При этом в dbeaver запрос `select * from "DB1"."table1"` выполняется успешно.

Python 3.9. Версии библиотек:
[image: Версии библиотек]

Comment: "A response of PGRES_EMPTY_QUERY often exposes a bug in the client software." Версии библиотек последние/свежие? Укажите версии всего в вопросе: питона, psycopg2 и т.д.

Comment: Версии выложил.

Comment: Версии последние. Ну не знаю даже куда копать. Без `Pandas` не пробовали просто запрос сделать программно через коннекшен?

Comment: Да, та же ошибка появляется
```cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM "DB1"."table1"')
all_users = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
conn.close()```

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию (и код) прямо в вопрос. Лишним не будет.